# Novel in which a hired killer muses about the existence of a legendary killer who operates only by accidents, followed by a short chapter of that man

Tags: identification-request

I think I read this as an ebook in English, within the last few years. The main character (not the only perspective character as I recall it) is a hired killer of some renown, and he was idly musing to himself about how fame in the world of killing was odd, because you also wanted to be unrecognizable, and he was thinking about a particular killer, legendary in the community for his anonymity and how he arranged the killings as seeming accidents. In particular, he mused that the killer might not actually exist, with actual accidents being ascribed to the killer. The next chapter was from the perspective of this legendary killer as he approached his victim (a political official?), expertly gauged an approaching car, and gave a shove at just the right time to kill his target and then melt into the crowd before people even registered the kill.

I don't think I finished the book, so I can't say if this accident killer showed up again, but it felt like a one-off, proof that some killers did keep their anonymity despite their fame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running through my reading history, and came upon *[Bullet Train](https://www.goodreads.com/is/book/show/56969543)* by Kotaro Isaka, which does involve multiple POVs from the killers. I misremembered a few details, like that it was the killer's handler mentioning the Pusher.

> There are a lot of candidates to choose from, after all. Like the Pusher. You’ve heard about him, right? The one who pushes his victims in front of cars or trains and makes their deaths look like an accident. Some people say he’s the best in the biz.

A few chapters later, we do get a POV story from the Pusher, who's remembering someone speculating that he didn't exist.

> Someone suddenly gets a cut on their arm or their leg, said the woman, and they scream, a kamaitachi got me! But really it was just a sharp wind. I think the Pusher must be the same sort of thing. Someone gets hit by a car or jumps in front of a train and people say it was the Pusher that did it. Couldn’t it just be a made-up story?

And indeed, he pushes a man.

> Cars come from the right. Black minivan, female driver, short hair, child seat in the back. The timing’s off. The next car is coincidentally the same type of minivan. The light changes. The car surges forward. Asagao casually moves his hand, touches the man’s back.
>
> There is the sound of impact, then the screech of the tyres clawing at the road. No one screams yet. The people’s shock is like a silent, transparent explosion.
>
> Asagao is already gone. He walks fluidly back the way he came, like floating on a current. Behind him he hears cries of Ambulance! but his heart is calm, like the surface of a lake where no pebble has been cast. His only thought is the vague recollection that he had once done a job at this same intersection, a long time ago.

That last line might be a reference to *[Three Assassins](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/58559387-three-assassins)* by the same author.

> Suzuki is just an ordinary man until his wife is murdered. When he discovers the criminal gang responsible he leaves behind his life as a maths teacher and joins them, looking for a chance to take his revenge. What he doesn't realise is that he's about to get drawn into a web of unusual professional assassins, each with their own agenda.
>
> The Whale convinces his victims to take their own lives using just his words.
> The Cicada is a talkative and deadly knife expert.
> The elusive Pusher dispatches his targets in deadly traffic accidents.
>
> Suzuki must take each of them on, in order to try to find justice and keep his innocence in a world of killers.